# How to create log of folder is read in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The folder of hdfs is like :

```
/test/data/2020-03-01/{multiple inside files csv}
/test/data/2020-03-02/{multiple files csv}
/test/data/2020-03-03/{multiple files csv }
```

i want to read data inside folder one by one not whole by

```
spark.read.csv("/test/data/*") //not in such manner
```

Not in above manner , i want to read file one by one; so that i can make the log entry in some database that  date folder is read ; so that on next time i can skip that folder in next day or same day if program run accidentally:

Answer (score 0):

```
val conf = new Configuration()
val iterate = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new URI(strOutput), conf).listLocatedStatus(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(strOutput))
while (iterate.hasNext) {
    val pathStr = iterate.next().getPath.toString
    println("log---->"+pathStr)
    val df = spark.read.text(pathStr) 
  }
```

Try something like above and read as data frame, if you want you can union new date df with old df.